# Cabal Multiple Executables

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a website using Yesod I have the normal build running but I can't seem to populate my database reliably. I have a second haskell program that populates the database and I've added it to my cabal file like this:

```
executable         program
  if flag(library-only)
    Buildable: False

  main-is:           ../main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:    dist
  build-depends:     base
                   , myproject
                   , yesod-default

executable         init
  if flag(library-only)
    Buildable: False

  main-is:           init.hs
  hs-source-dirs:    Init
  build-depends:     base
                   , directory
                   , persistent
                   , persistent-sqlite
                   , text
                   , myproject
                   , yesod-default
```

The problem is that when I run 'cabal build' it does not rebuild init when init.hs changes. What do I have to do to make this happen?

Here's an example terminal session (after editing init.hs):

```
$ cabal build
Building myproject-0.0.0...
Preprocessing library myproject-0.0.0...
Registering myproject-0.0.0...
$ rm -rf dist/build/myproject/init
$ cabal build
Building myproject-0.0.0...
Preprocessing library myproject-0.0.0...
Registering myproject-0.0.0...
```

Thank you.

Comment: The question title mentions multiple executables.  Is there another executable stanza that doesn't have this problem in the same cabal file?

Comment: Are you sure `init` doesn't get rebuilt? You'll have to look under `dist/build` to see the new executable, or run `cabal install` if you want the new executable put somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated the cabal snippet above. When I modify init.hs (which is located inside the Init/ directory) it doesn't recompile anything. cabal runs and exits without any ghc invocations. I have a symlink to the executable in dist/build that I am using to run the code.

Comment: I probably don't really understand what you are doing here: For `executable program`, why do you have `hs-source-dirs` to be set to cabal's `dist/` folder but then say that `main-is` is outside of that folder, in your current folder? I've never seen this before and dont understand what the intention is.

Answer (score 9):

You can manage multiple executables by passing them as arguments to `cabal build` and `cabal run`. For example, `cabal build init`. The first executable is the default if no target name is given.