# When you depend on a cabal package, it seems to draw in dependencies in all cabal stanzas

Tags: haskell, cabal

I made my own cabal package (let's call it package-1) with two targets, a library and a executable. The library section has a build-depends list, and the executable has another build-depends list that is much larger.

Now I create package-2, which lists package-1 in its build-depends section. I would like to only bring in the dependencies listed in the *library* target of package-1. But it seems to bring in *all* the dependencies listed in all the sections of package-1, including the dependencies for the executable target.

Is there any way to prune the dependency graph to just the library inside package-1, or do I have to resort to breaking out that library target into a separate standalone package?

Comment: This is a well-known and long-standing issue, a question has been asked on SO (it's a dupe), and some workarounds exist.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I've seen this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163604/how-to-reduce-duplication-in-the-build-depends-fields-of-a-cabal-file?rq=1 which you may be referring to, but my question is different.

Answer (score 3):

You can put `Buildable: False` to executable, and then build it explicitly when needed with `cabal build Foo`, or via flag (`cabal configure -fbuild-foo` or `-fbuild-executables`).

Example that might be helpful: [Cabal Multiple Executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745583/cabal-multiple-executables)